# What's a word that means the strength of an alliance without confusing it with how strong the alliance is in combination

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a more appropriate word than strength to describe the amount of dedication to the alliance the parties have without confusing it with how strong the parties are as individuals.

Sentence example: I have full faith in the strength of our alliance with Jenny.

Answer (score 0):

[Solidarity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solidarity) (Wiktionary) (*countable*) A bond of unity or agreement between individuals, united around a common goal or against a common enemy, such as the unifying principle that defines the labor movement; mutual support within a group. (*uncountable*) Willingness to give psychological and/or material support when another person is in a difficult position or needs affection.

[Concinnity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concinnity) (Merriam Webster) : harmony or elegance of design especially of literary style in adaptation of parts to a whole or to each other.

[Synergy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/synergy) (Collins Dictionary)(variable noun) If there is synergy between two or more organizations or groups, they are more successful when they work together than when they work separately.